# Typescript arrow function with signature accepts wrong parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, arrow-functions

Consider the type:

```
type GenericFunction = <T>(props: Array<T>) => void
```

and the arrow function:

```
const test: GenericFunction = <X>(props: X) => {
let dd: X }
```

How come that the `test` function accepts `X` as argument although the type `GenericFunction` defines `Array<T>`
as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are types for `X` that will satisfy the signature of `GenericFunction`,  that's why the compiler does not give an error. Theres is just an implicit constraint now that `X` must be an array type.

Only if you add a constraint for `X` that conflicts with this implicit constraint you get an error:

```
// this gives a compile error
const test: GenericFunction = <X extends number>(props: X) => {};
```

Comment: This is understandable but it looks kind of incorrect to me. For example the `test` function is going to be called like `test<number>(new Array<number>())`. So in my mind `X` in this case represents number and not `Array<number>`